# Aligning text baseline across flexbox containers in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to create this layout:

[image]

I can get most of the way using flexbox and `align-self: baseline`:

```
<div style="background-color: #fce5cdff; display: flex; height: 4.35cm;">
  <div style="font-size: 24pt">Ferry to Brookfield</div>
  <div style="font-size: 96pt; align-self: baseline">3</div>
  <div style="font-size: 9pt; align-self: baseline">min</div>
</div>
```

[This looks like (JSFiddle):](https://jsfiddle.net/cwnxhy65/0/)

[image]

From here, I can't figure out how to add the text "leave in" so that its baseline aligns with the text "3 min". [Here's an attempt (JSFiddle).](https://jsfiddle.net/cwnxhy65/1/)

How can I create this layout in CSS?

Comment: Almost impossible, character glyphs are **supposed** to have vertical space above and below. In fact it's baked into the font.

Comment: Note that `pt` is for print, not the web. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```html
<div style="background-color: #fce5cdff; display: flex; height: 4.35cm;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;justify-content: space-between">
        <div>
            <h1 style="font-size: 24pt;font-weight:300;margin-bottom:47px">Ferry to Brookfield</h1>
            <div style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: right;">leave in</div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 96pt">3<span style="font-size:9pt">min</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with `absolute` positioning and pseudo elements:

```css
.wrapper{
  background-color: #fce5cdff;
  display: flex;
  height: 4.35cm;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
span{
  font-size: 96pt;
 line-height: 96pt;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 2pt;
}
span::before {
  content: "leave in";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10pt;
  bottom: 6pt;
  left: -6ch;
}
span::after {
  content: "min";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10pt;
  bottom: 6pt;
  right: -3ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    Ferry to Brookfield <span>3</span>
</div>
```